# iMac late 2009 new ssd install

Tags: keyboard, imac, hardware, recovery

So I’ve read through a lot of “new install” threads and all are pretty much the same...use internet recovery or cmd+r on boot up.

But here’s my issue.

My old hdd crashed so I don’t have anything to recover from. The new ssd is installed and boots to the flashing folder ? Question mark. I can’t seem to cmd r because it doesn’t see the Bluetooth keyboard. I’ve tried a pc keyboard with no luck. So here I am trying to figure out how to format this new ssd.

Any suggestions?

Comment: My Windows keyboard does not work when holding down the cmd+r key.

Answer (score 1):

The Windows key is the command key by default. Unless you have a fancy programmable keyboard and have changed things, try holding the alt key which boots to the boot chooser just to be sure the keyboard and USB are functioning.

If you had a newer Mac, then you can try again with recovery or internet recovery:

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314
- [What keyboards can reliably be used to start up recovery or diagnostics mode on a Mac mini?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/347779/what-keyboards-can-reliably-be-used-to-start-up-recovery-or-diagnostics-mode-on)

In your case the 2009 iMac needs bootable media so you probably need to bring another Mac and target disk mode or create a bootable installer. The PC keyboard will work now that you know Windows key is Command and Alt is Option, but you’ll need bootable media to continue.